# OnClick on custom view is not working

Tags: android, dynamic, view, onclick

I have a `LinearLayout` where I need to add custom view dynamically. custom view is added properly. but now i want to set on click on that view. I have tired it.

```
BlockView localView = new BlockView(getApplicationContext(),
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

localView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
});
layoutBox.addView(localView);
```

**BlockView.java**

```
public class BlockView extends View{

    Bitmap mBitmap;

    Drawable mDrawable;
    private int drawableWidth, drawableHeight;
    private int viewWidth, viewHeight, layoutHeight, layoutWidth;
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Paint mBorderPaint;

    public BlockView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public BlockView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    }

    public BlockView(Context paramContext, Bitmap bmp, int layoutHeight,
            int layoutWidth) {
        super(paramContext);
        this.mBitmap = bmp;
        this.layoutHeight = layoutHeight;
        this.layoutWidth = layoutWidth;
        mBorderPaint = new Paint();
        // mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mBorderPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        buildDrawingCache(true);

        mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        drawableWidth = mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        drawableHeight = mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        viewWidth = layoutWidth;
        viewHeight = layoutHeight;

        setMeasuredDimension(viewWidth, viewHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        try {   

            int saveCount = canvas.save();

            float scale;
            float dx;
            float dy;

            if (drawableWidth <= viewWidth && drawableHeight <= viewHeight) {
                scale = 1.0f;
            } else {
                scale = Math.min((float) viewWidth / (float) drawableWidth,
                        (float) viewHeight / (float) drawableHeight);
            }

            dx = (int) ((viewWidth - drawableWidth * scale) * 0.5f + 0.5f);
            dy = (int) ((viewHeight - drawableHeight * scale) * 0.5f + 0.5f);

            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
            matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);

            canvas.concat(matrix);

            mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawableWidth, drawableHeight);
            mDrawable.draw(canvas);

            canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("onDraw: ", ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

But `onClick` is not working.I don't know where i am going wrong.

Help me to fix it !!

Comment: Paste your custom view class i.e. BlockView in this case

Comment: Have you printed in your `Log` or checked with `Toast`????

Comment: yes. i have checked with log and toast as well. it is not going inside on click().

Comment: Show your full Activity class here.

Comment: Till now in activity, I have done only task of picking image and then adding that image in that custom view.

Comment: I think maybe you should be returning `false` in your `onTouchEvent()` method.

Comment: i think your onTouchEvent() is consuming your onClick() event, you can try @Mike's suggestion.

Comment: If i comment OnTouchListener(), then onClick is working properly. But i want both thing.

Answer (score 0):

**First you need to addView() on layout and after that need to register clickLisner.**

```
layoutBox.addView(localView);  // this line will become first.

localView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
});
```

Comment: please add this line in onTouch():  `super.onTouchEvent(event)` at first line, before return true in BlockView class;

Comment: thanks. by adding super.onTouchEvent(event);, atleast onclick has started working. to made it work, i have to comment OnTouchListener. but i want both thing.

Comment: why are you want both things? i think you can write your logic in setOnClickListner() itself ?

Comment: On onTouch, i have to perform gestures(zoom,rotate,translate) on image. thats why i need both.

Comment: ok then you can call `super.onTouchEvent(event)` in last line , after your gestures() function it will work for both.

Comment: I am not getting why onTouch event is consuming my onClick event ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the onclickListener generated automatically, I mean you should use View.OnClickListener. If that is not used you can't override the onClickListener

```
localView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
});
layoutBox.addView(localView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this hope it will help you

```
//   viewHolder is your View Custom view    

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
        if (l == null) {
            viewHolder.setOnClickListener(null);
            mParentOnClickListener = null;
        } else {
            viewHolder.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
            mParentOnClickListener = l;
        }
    }

    private View.OnClickListener mParentOnClickListener;
    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mParentOnClickListener != null) {
                mParentOnClickListener.onClick(YourCustomView.this);
            }
        }
    };
```